# Создать окно изменений поля Tedit

Tags: c++, vcl

Начал осваивать VCL и столкнулся с проблемой. Как и с чем связать поле ввода `Tedit`, чтобы то, что вводилось в него, вывелось на экран как в чате (вроде истории введенного)?

Нигде не нашел нормальных туториалов на эту тему.

Comment: Через событие. Наверно OnChange обработчик.

Comment: Речь про RAD Studio/C++ Builder? Там же справка есть.

Comment: @älёxölüt в моей версии при попытке нажать на справку, выходит ошибка